# Excel countifs with multiple wildcard matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to look at data representing network traffic flows between systems (source, destination and port) against previously requested firewall rules.  This will filter observed data to only items of interest. I have 3 named arrays (source, dest, port) which represent the existing rules.  Each rule can have one or more hostnames (actually FQDNs) in it - usually separated by char(10), but they were made manually so anything goes.  All I really want to know is if my current source, destination and port all show up in the same rule.  Here is the formula I'm trying:

```
=COUNTIFS(source,"*"&B2&"*",dest,"*"&A2&"*",port,"*"&C2&"*")
```

Even though it looks odd, I do have my data organized by destination as that is a better way to group the traffic, so the cell numbers above are not out of order.  The cells in question

**Result**
Right now all of the copies of this formula are returning 0.

What I tried:

1. I fixed the fact that case is different by making sure the named ranges are upper() and the FQDNs I produce in my flow table are also upper().
2. I looked at the defined names to make sure they are pointing at the data that I expect.  They do and they all look at the entire column, so they are all the same size
   3)I also just tried to add a test row in the named columns to match the first row in my data exactly and countifs still returned 0.
3. Also tried to be more explicit in my formula

```
=COUNTIFS(source,"=*"&B2&"*",dest,"=*"&A2&"*",port,"=*"&C2&"*")
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Case is immaterial to COUNTIFS. You'll have to check your criteria very carefully - at least one must be wrong. Try starting with one, see if that works, then expand.

Comment: OK, so I tried multiple scenarios of formula edits (start with initial formula and then delete).  Here are the results:  Source-only:  All 3 scenarios with only one data point being checked work.  If I removed just source or just dest it did not work.  If I removed just port it did.  My next hypothesis is that maybe it was a data type thing where I was comparing port as number and string.  Changed all to text.  Didn't help.

Comment: If I change my port value from "80" to "TestPort" in the test data, all permutations work.  Then I tried '80 instead of 80 for the port cell value in both flow and data.  That worked.  So new question:  I thought changing to "Text" under number format would convert everything to text.  Apparently it isn't doing "enough".  How do I change everything to text?

Comment: You changed it to text, but did you really change it to text? If the values were already numbers and then you formatted the column to text, then they are still numbers unless you do one more step after the format change. There are several ways to make them text, such as text to columns, or copy/paste to and back from notepad, etc... Once you see the green triangle warning, then you know they are text.

Comment: Do you actually need wildcards with your port numbers?

Comment: Yes.  Sometimes the port says tcp/443.  Sometimes it is a list of ports separated by char(10), sometimes there are commas.  Sometimes it just says 445 and turns into a number

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in fact the mix of numbers and text in the port column.  The fix was to simply manually add a column to the data with the formula:

```
=Text(f2,"0")
```

where f2 is the first instance of port information in my prior FW rule requests.  I did the same thing in my flow data to make sure it is always text to text

I would have solved it sooner, but while testing I inadvertently clobbered some data and didn't realize that many of my rules no longer had source names.

As mentioned by Rory above, it was not necessary to force the uppercase match.